# Difference in behavior of struct.unpack in Python 2.7 Vs 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am converting a codebase from Python 2.7 to Python 3.6. I have this code:

```
import struct 

unpacked = struct.unpack('<BI6s', '\x02\xff\x01\x00\x00tester', offset=0)
```

In Python 2.7, `unpacked = (2, 511, 'tester')`, which is what I want.

In Python 3.6, since `struct.unpack` expects the second argument to be `bytes`, I tried the following:

```
import struct 

unpacked = struct.unpack('<BI6s', bytes('\x02\xff\x01\x00\x00tester', 'utf8'), offset=0)
```

And `unpacked = (2, 114627, b'\x00teste')`.

Why am I getting a different result and how do I get the same result I was getting in 2.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the `bytes()` call:

```
>>> bytes('\x02\xff\x01\x00\x00tester', 'utf8')
b'\x02\xc3\xbf\x01\x00\x00tester'
```

See the extra bytes `\xc3\xbf`? Python 3 strings are unicode, and the UTF-8 encoding for the second character in your string (`U+00FF`) is 0xC3 0xBF (see https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00FF).

The solution is to use a bytes literal, which has the same behaviour as Python 2:

```
unpacked = struct.unpack('<BI6s', b'\x02\xff\x01\x00\x00tester', offset=0)
```